# What exactly is considered a גרמא?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, rishonim, grama

I faintly recall some Rishon saying that גרמא means something that doesn't happen right away but takes at least a few seconds to happen. Does anyone know the source for that, or anyone that disagrees?

Comment: For shabbos or nizikin? Maybe you are thinking of koach kocho...